# Thread Join Method. Can main thread complete before other Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know how the thread join method works, but i have a sample question. Please see the example code below

```
public class RunnableJob implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("Runnable job is run by" + currentThread.getName());
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadExample{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        RunnableJob runnableJob = new RunnableJob();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T2");
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T3");
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T4");

        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
        thread3.start();
        thread3.join();
        thread4.start();
        thread4.join();

        Thread thread5 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T5");
        Thread thread6 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T6");
        Thread thread7 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T7");
        Thread thread8 = new Thread(runnableJob,"T8");

        thread5.start();
        thread6.start();
        thread7.start();
        thread8.start();



    }
}
```

I know that, T1,T2,T3,T4 will block the main thread, before they complete. But is it possible that before T5,T6,T7,T8 actually start running, the main thread completes and T5..T8, remain in runnable state only. If this is possible, how can i produce the same?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "produce the same"?

Comment: Means is it possible that main thread finishes before t5 to t8 if it is possible can I replicate same effect?

Comment: Any thread can finish in any order.  Nothing special happens when the "main" thread finishes, unless it is the last non daemon thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you are looking for to answer your question is "daemon" threads. As long as there are non-daemon threads running, the application will not terminate and those threads will be able to run to a terminated state.

In your case, therefore, T5...T8 will run and complete as they are non-daemon threads <sup>†</sup>.

From the documentation for [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> •The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
>
> •All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method

<sup>†</sup> *In fact the original single non-daemon thread started by the JVM may enter the terminated state before T5...T8 do. That will not stop T5...T8 running to completion in this case.*

Comment: ? i don't interpret this to mean the main thread won't terminate, it just means the jvm instance will stick around until all the nondaemon threads are finished.

Comment: @NathanHughes - you are right, it was sloppy wording on my part. I was focused on the "will T5...T8 remain in the runnable state only" part of the question.